# Docker compose python scripts, postgresql database error psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "postgres" to address

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

python scripts Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.11-slim

# Set the working directory in the container
ARG FUNCTION_DIR=/app
WORKDIR ${FUNCTION_DIR}

#requirements and dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y postgresql-server-dev-all gcc python3-dev musl-dev g++ make
COPY requirements.txt ${FUNCTION_DIR}
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/pip pip install -r  requirements.txt
RUN python3 -m spacy download en_core_web_trf  

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY /alembic ${FUNCTION_DIR}/alembic
COPY /app ${FUNCTION_DIR}/app
COPY /config ${FUNCTION_DIR}/config
COPY /docker ${FUNCTION_DIR}/docker
COPY /erd ${FUNCTION_DIR}/erd
COPY /notebooks ${FUNCTION_DIR}/notebooks
COPY /sample_data ${FUNCTION_DIR}/sample_data
COPY /scripts ${FUNCTION_DIR}/scripts
COPY /templates ${FUNCTION_DIR}/templates
COPY /tests ${FUNCTION_DIR}/tests
COPY /web_apps ${FUNCTION_DIR}/web_apps
COPY .env ${FUNCTION_DIR}
```

python container is not running server, rather it has some scripts for execution.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  qdrant:
    image: qdrant/qdrant:latest
    volumes:
      - ${DOCKER_VOLUME_DIRECTORY:-.}/volumes/qdrant:/qdrant/storage
    ports:
      - "6333:6333"
    networks:
      - mynetwork

  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      POSTGRES_HOST: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
    volumes:
      - ${DOCKER_VOLUME_DIRECTORY:-.}/volumes/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - mynetwork

  advocacy-app:
    container_name: advocacy-app
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: app/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - qdrant
      - postgres
    networks:
      - mynetwork

networks:
  mynetwork:
    driver: bridge
```

config.yaml

```
postgres:
  host: postgres
  port: 5432
  user: postgres
  password: postgres
  database: falcon
```

database_con.py

```
from psycopg2 import pool

class DatabasePool:
    _instance = None
    _pool = None

    def __new__(cls, config):
        if cls._instance is None:
            cls._instance = super(DatabasePool, cls).__new__(cls)
            cls._pool = pool.SimpleConnectionPool(1, 20,
                                                  user=config['postgres']['user'],
                                                  password=config['postgres']['password'], 
                                                  host=config['postgres']['host'],
                                                  port=config['postgres']['port'],
                                                  database=config['postgres']['database'])
        return cls._instance

    @classmethod
    def get_connection(cls):
        return cls._pool.getconn()

    @classmethod
    def put_connection(cls, conn):
        cls._pool.putconn(conn)
```

whenever i try to run app container with

docker run advocacy-app python3 app/pipeline.py

it gives error

psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "postgres" to address

Comment: In your `config.yaml` file, didn't you mean to use `postgres` in `postgres.host`? `localhost:5432` is not reachable on the `advocacy` container because it does not run any postgres database.

Comment: i've tried changing host from "localhost" to "postgres" (as my container name is), but still gave me same error. I've edited the question. thanks for typo

Comment: `docker run` doesn't read the Compose setup at all: it doesn't start the database and doesn't attach the container to the Compose network.  Do you mean `docker-compose up -d`?  (Don't forget to include `CMD ["app/pipeline.py"]` in your Dockerfile so you don't have to repeat it when you run the container.)

Comment: Ok thanks I got you. But what if I have multiple scripts to run sequentially like app/pipeline.py then app/run.py, what would be the optimal solution?

Comment: Please note that the recommended file name for docker compose files is `compose.yaml` (although other forms are accepted for backwards compatibility). Apart from that the officially recommended extension for YAML files has been `.yaml` since at least September 2006.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, wrote a script to constantly run container
e.g

```
RUN CMD ["python3","app/main.py"]
```

compose using

```
docker-compose run --rm advocacy-app
```

this will compose other two containers with same network as advocacy-app container that will run as interactive python script